# is split function derivable

Tags: calculus, derivatives, special-functions

$ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{sin(x)}{x},  & x \ne0 \\
x+1, & x=0
\end{cases}$

I know that the function is a continuous function in R.
But is this function derivable at x=0?

I am not sure..

Thanks

Comment: Step 1: Write down the definition of "derivable".

Comment: So it doesn't have anything to do with what is happening with the function at the point 0?

Comment: of course it does.  The limit will not exist if $f(0)$ is anything but $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RHS:
lim$_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\dfrac{\sin h-h}{h^2}$

On applying L'Hospital's Rule twice we get limit 0

Similarly LHS:

$\dfrac{f(0)-f(-h)}{h}=\dfrac{h-\sin h}{h^2}(\dfrac{0}{0})$

On applying L'Hospital's Rule twice we get limit 0

Thus differentiable at 0

Comment: So it doesn't have anything to do with what is happening with the function at the point 0?

Comment: from my computation it seems so

Comment: Hold on, Lee. Learnmore just explained that $f'(0) = 0$ But he did that in the correct way, by using the definition and NOT by taking the derivative with the standard rules on the given function.